# Format error when converting bytes to an image

Tags: java, image

For my code, I get a byte array and need to convert it to an image. After searching I came up with this.

```
byte[] data = (byte array here)

Files.createFile(Paths.get("./test.png"));
File file = new File("./test.png");
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(bis);
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", file);
```

I get no errors when running this code. It creates a file and everything goes fine until I open it. It gives me an error saying this file format isn't supported. I have tried changing it to jpg and bmp formats. That doesn't work either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: This is the error I am getting]

Comment: I forgot to include that this is a socket network program so it is multiplayer. When converting everyone on the client side it works fine. When it reaches the server it breaks. So I have concluded it is a problem with my server and not my code.

Comment: The code as is, should work fine, even though `Files.createFile(...)` is unnecessary. But it will of course not work for all inputs (`data`), so we are only seeing half the problem here... If `bi` is non-`null`, at least your input is a valid image file. Note that `ImageIO.write(..)` returns a.`boolean` indicating success. If it is `false`, I would guess that `test.png` is an empty file.